# Why is my HTTPS server asking for credentials while using standard port 44398?

Tags: c#, http, networking, https, server

I tried setting up a web server using [C# HttpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-5.0). I made a port reservation with netsh on port 44398 which already contains an SSL certificate in windows. And now when I go to the page with a browser I get a request for credentials. At this point I don't know what to do next.

If someone could help me that would be great!

Comment: What is the AuthenticationSchemes configured in your HTTP listener ?

Comment: Oh I was so stupid! I switched from "IntegratedWindowsAuthentication" to "Anonymous" and now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: SSL is a authentication protocol that is done before an HTTP Request is made and has nothing to do with a login credential.